# Connect to user account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, admin

My app is on RoR.
I'm using devise and rails admin.

The platform has some users.
Sometime, admin account needs to access / login to their account.

Do you any ideas how to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Devise has a module for this, https://github.com/oivoodoo/devise_masquerade .  I have used this and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might need it's an "impersonation" system to be able to act as the user.

There's a known solution for Ruby On Rails called [Pretender](https://github.com/ankane/pretender) that you can easily integrate with your project.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use Devise `sign_in` method, like this: `sign_in(@user)`.
You will be authorized as user you've passed to sign_in method.

Or you can use `sign_in_and_redirect` method, which will redirect you to another page after login.

Documentation: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FControllers%2FHelpers:sign_in_and_redirect